# MS Cognitive custom voice-submitting sample data-returning "Only the RIFF(WAV) format is accepted. Check the format of your audio files."

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

Just checking to make sure that this should be supported.  The page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-customize-voice-font#prepare-recordings-and-transcripts) says that you should be able to use any PCM file that's at least 16kHz.  I'm trying to segment a longer wav file into utterances using NAudio, and I can generate the files, but all of the training data that I submit is coming back with the processing error "Only the RIFF(WAV) format is accepted. Check the format of your audio files."  The audio files are 16 bit PCM, mono, 44kHz wav files, and are all under 60s. Is there another constraint on the file format that I might be missing?  The wav files do have a valid RIFF header (verified that the bytes exist).

Comment: You can share the sample of your file to get help on this issue.

Comment: Can you share the sample code?

Comment: Sure, sample audio file posted at https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asf277jGvfFnmrZx-S0UNQgbDPs3jQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by explicitly re-encoding audio that I received back from the SpeechRecognizer.  Definitely not an efficient solution, but this was just a hack to test things out.  Here's the code for reference (put this in Recognizer.Recognized):

```
string rawResult = ea.Result.ToString();  //can get access to raw value this way.
Regex r = new Regex(@".*Offset"":(\d*),.*");
UInt64 offset = Convert.ToUInt64(r?.Match(rawResult)?.Groups[1]?.Value);
r = new Regex(@".*Duration"":(\d*),.*");
UInt64 duration = Convert.ToUInt64(r?.Match(rawResult)?.Groups[1]?.Value);

//create segment files
File.AppendAllText($@"{path}\{fileName}\{fileName}.txt", $"{segmentNumber}\t{ea.Result.Text}\r\n");

//offset and duration are in 100ns units
WaveFileReader w = new WaveFileReader(v);
long totalDurationInMs = w.SampleCount / w.WaveFormat.SampleRate * 1000;  //total length of the file
ulong offsetInMs = offset / 10000;  //convert from 100ns intervals to ms
ulong durationInMs = duration / 10000;
long bytesPerMilliseconds = w.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000;
w.Position = bytesPerMilliseconds * (long)offsetInMs;
long bytesToRead = bytesPerMilliseconds * (long)durationInMs;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
int bytesRead = w.Read(buffer, 0, (int)bytesToRead);
string wavFileName = $@"{path}\{fileName}\{segmentNumber}.wav";
string tempFileName = wavFileName + ".tmp";
WaveFileWriter wr = new WaveFileWriter(tempFileName, w.WaveFormat);
wr.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
wr.Close();

//this is probably really inefficient, but it's also the simplest way to get things in the right format.  It's a prototype-deal with it...
WaveFileReader r2 = new WaveFileReader(tempFileName);
//from other project
var desiredOutputFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);
using (var converter = new WaveFormatConversionStream(desiredOutputFormat, r2))
{
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(wavFileName, converter);
}

segmentNumber++;
```

This splits the input file to separate per-turn files, and appends the turn transcripts in the text file using the filenames.

The good news is that this produced a "valid" dataset, and I was able to create a voice from it.  The bad news is that the voice font produced audio that was almost completely unintelligible, which I'm going to attribute to a combination of using machine-transcribed samples along with irregular turn breaks and possibly noisy audio.  I may see if there's anything that can be done to improve the accuracy by hand editing a few files, but I at least wanted to post an answer here in case anyone else has the same problem.

Also, it appears that either 16 KHz and 44 KHz PCM will work with custom voice, so that's a plus if you have higher quality audio available.